# Cant understand what predict() does in this case

Tags: r, regression, predict, dummy-variable

I am looking at some code that prepares a dataframe for several prediction models to be tested later on. The general idea is to predict NormSec based on all the other columns. 
Not sure what predict(dummies,newdata=data) does in this case.

I know that predict is used to predict based on an already trained fit. Why is it used in this case? The code works, just trying to understand it.

```
data<-read.csv(file="datatable.csv")
attach(data)

#selecting the useful columns from data table:
data<-data.frame(NormSec, Rivalry,Stars,NormFB,SeasonPart,FootballSeason,LeBron,Weekend,LastSeasonWins
 ,Holiday,BigGame,OverUnders,DaysSinceLast,DaysUntilNext, Weekday, Monthday, NewArena)


dummies <- dummyVars(NormSec~., data = data)
attach(dummies)

#Here is the function I don't get:
dataDescr<-predict(dummies,newdata=data)


dataDescr<-data.frame(dataDescr)
attach(dataDescr)
```

dummies is a dummy variable object and DataDescr (output of predict()) is the original dataframe without the NormSec column.

Comment: 1) Where does `dummyVars` come from? You should start the scripts with call(s) to `library(pkgname)` to load the necessary packages. 2) Please don't use `attach`, it makes code difficult to understand.

Comment: My b, dummyVars comes from the {caret} package. All the packages are loaded together in the beginning of the code. The code above is a small part of a larger script which I didn't include to make my question clearer.  I only want to understand why we use predict() to

Comment: Basically my question is what does predict(list, newdata=data) does? I am only familiar with the use of predict() in the following way : predict(fit, newdata=data)

Comment: If you fit a model with `data`, as in `fit <- fitFunction(formula, data = data)` then `predict(fit)` and `predict(fit, newdata = data)` are the same thing. Argument `newdata` is meant for out of sample data.

Comment: I am not asking for the difference between predict(fit) and predict(fit, newdata = data). I am asking for the difference between predict(fit) an predict(list). In the case above we use predict(list) where list is the dummyVars list.

Comment: But that's the same thing. If you predict with `newdata = original_data` the result is a dataframe of the fitted values, you cannot expect to have `predict.dummyVars` (the `predict` method for objects of class `"dummyVars"`) give more than what is passed to it.